# using similarity of triangles, how it implements the persepctive projection

Tags: graphics, perspectivecamera

I am doing revision on graphics module, but im unsure how to answer the following question.

Can someone please help me with this? thanks

[revision question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sosW5.jpg)

Comment: Please walk through the [help] and [ask]. The question is off-topic on StackOverflow (try [math.se] instead) because it is not about programming.

Comment: Or perhaps you could try https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/